# Where does the Raspberry PI 3 b+ IO peripherals mapped in the Linux kernel virtual address space?

Tags: linux-kernel, raspberry-pi, raspberry-pi3, memory-mapping

[BCM 2835 data sheet](https://www.raspberrypi.org/app/uploads/2012/02/BCM2835-ARM-Peripherals.pdf)
The earlier version of Raspberry PI (BCM 2835) data sheet shows that the IO Peripherals are mapped from starting address -

> 1. 0x20000000 - In ARM physical address space
> 2. 0xF2000000 - In Kernel virtual address space

I am aware that the Raspberry PI 3B+ (BCM 2837) and BCM 2836 is mostly similar to BCM 2835 and that is the reason there is no separate data sheet available for both 2836 and 2837. There is a difference in the memory map on the Raspberry PI3 B+, The IO peripherals are mapped from starting address `0x3F000000` instead of `0x20000000` in ARM physical address space.

I am not sure if the kernel virtual address map in RPI 3b+ is still same as the previous version i.e starting at address `0xF2000000`, or it is mapped to a different location ?

Please help me to understand this.

Comment: It can be mapped to any page as kernel decides, so, you shouldn’t care about virtual addresses at all

Comment: https://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/
Seems suitable site for this question.

Comment: May be I could not explain the question properly. If you look at this document. 
https://www.raspberrypi.org/app/uploads/2012/02/BCM2835-ARM-Peripherals.pdf
Page 5 shows that the "IO base address in kernel ARCH is 0xF2000000" in "ARM virtual address".   So I was curious on what addresses it will be mapped in RPI 3B+